# Continuous function and increasing property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that $f(x)$ is continuous function. Also, we have that for all $y>0$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $x \in (y-\epsilon, y)$ we have $f(x)<f(y)$.
From this I want to prove that $f(x)$ is increasing function.

To prove this I assume $f$ is not increasing and try to prove this by contradiction. If I negate $f$ is increasing then that means for $x<x+1$, $f(x)>f(x+1)$. Then how to finish this proof?

Here is what I've tried so far. When we assume that $f$ is not increasing that means that we can find a interval that for all $x \in (y-\epsilon,y_*)$, ($y_*<y$), we have $f(x)>f(y_*)$. Then (from the fact that for all $y$ there exists $\epsilon$), for $y_*$ there exists $\epsilon_*>0$ such that for all $x \in (y_*-\epsilon_*,y_*)$ we have $f(x)<f(y_*)$. That contradicts our assumption, $f(x)>f(y_*)$.

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: What is your definition of an increasing function?  That may be useful here I'd think.

Comment: should remove $y>0$ condition--otherwise $|x|$ becomes counter-ex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f(a)>f(b)$ with $b>a$ then by EVT (extreme value theorem) you must attain a minimum on [a,b].Any $ c\in (a,b]$ can't have minimum value by the given $\varepsilon$-condition. And $f(a)$ also can't be minimum by our assumption.
So ,we get a contradiction . . .

Comment: we must attain a min on [a,b] and also, cannot have min in (a,b]. That means only possible choice of c is a? so f(a) is min? but it contradict?

Comment: @Keith    It contradicts $f(a)>f(b)$ so our assumption is wrong --f is increasing everywhere..

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$\inf \{x| f(t)\leq f(y) \forall t\in (x,y) \}= -\infty$